# My JPEG files are showing a gradle error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

There is a gradle error in my *Android Studio*. The `.jpg` files stored in the "Assets" folder are showing the error that they should end in `.xml` format only.

I use those image files in the HTML webpage for the web-view activity - hence its stored there.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Change the extension from .jpg to .gif and see if that works! It worked for me some time ago